# Calculating the angle between two vectors using a needle-like triangle

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, numeric, floating-accuracy

I implemented a function (`angle_between`) to calculate the angle between two vectors. It makes use of needle-like triangles and is based on [Miscalculating Area and Angles of a Needle-like Triangle](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Triangle.pdf) and [this related question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27689/numerically-stable-way-of-computing-angles-between-vectors).

The function appears to work fine most of the time, except for one weird case where I don't understand what is happening:

```py
import numpy as np
vectorA = np.array([0.008741225033460295, 1.1102230246251565e-16], dtype=np.float64)
vectorB = np.array([1, 0], dtype=np.float64)
angle_between(vectorA, vectorB)  # is np.nan
```

Digging into my function, the `np.nan` is produced by taking the square root of a negative number, and the negative number seems to be the result of the increased accuracy of the method:

```py
foo = 1.0                  # np.linalg.norm(vectorA)
bar = 0.008741225033460295 # np.linalg.norm(vectorB)
baz = 0.9912587749665397   # np.linalg.norm(vectorA- vectorB)

# algebraically equivalent ... numerically not so much
order1 = baz - (foo - bar)
order2 = bar - (foo - baz)

assert order1 == 0
assert order2 == -1.3877787807814457e-17
```

According to Kahan's paper, this means that the triplet (foo, bar, baz) actually doesn't represent the side lengths of a triangle. However, this should - in fact - be the case given how I constructed the triangle (see the comments in the code).

From here, I feel a bit lost as to where to look for the source of the error. Could somebody explain to me what is happening?

---

For completeness, here is the full code of my function:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def angle_between(
    vec_a: ArrayLike, vec_b: ArrayLike, *, axis: int = -1, eps=1e-10
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Computes the angle from a to b

    Notes
    -----
    Implementation is based on this post:
    https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/27694
    """

    vec_a = np.asarray(vec_a)[None, :]
    vec_b = np.asarray(vec_b)[None, :]

    if axis >= 0:
        axis += 1

    len_c = np.linalg.norm(vec_a - vec_b, axis=axis)
    len_a = np.linalg.norm(vec_a, axis=axis)
    len_b = np.linalg.norm(vec_b, axis=axis)

    mask = len_a >= len_b
    tmp = np.where(mask, len_a, len_b)
    np.putmask(len_b, ~mask, len_a)
    len_a = tmp

    mask = len_c > len_b
    mu = np.where(mask, len_b - (len_a - len_c), len_c - (len_a - len_b))

    numerator = ((len_a - len_b) + len_c) * mu
    denominator = (len_a + (len_b + len_c)) * ((len_a - len_c) + len_b)

    mask = denominator > eps
    angle = np.divide(numerator, denominator, where=mask)
    np.sqrt(angle, out=angle)
    np.arctan(angle, out=angle)
    angle *= 2
    np.putmask(angle, ~mask, np.pi)
    return angle[0]
```

**Edit:** The problem is definitely related to `float64` and disappears when performing the computation with larger floats:

```py
import numpy as np

vectorA = np.array([0.008741225033460295, 1.1102230246251565e-16], dtype=np.float128)
vectorB = np.array([1, 0], dtype=np.float128)
assert angle_between(vectorA, vectorB) == 0
```

Comment: Recall that 3 sides make up a triangle if they satisfy the strong triangle inequality i.e. the sum of the two shorter sides must be strictly bigger than the longer side. But that's not the case for you since `bar + baz == 1 == foo`.

Comment: @user2640045 I guess `bar + baz == 1 == foo` comes from floating point inaccuracies? The lengths of the three vectors `vectorA`, `vectorB`, `vectorA - vectorB` should always form a valid triangle, no? Beyond that, the two degenerate cases of `vectorA == vectorB` and `vectorA == -vectorB` should be handled correctly by the function. The former by `len_c` being 0 and the latter by `np.putmask(angle, ~mask, np.pi)`.

Comment: Nope there is also the case when vectorA and vectorB are a multiple of each other. Which is almost the case here. If I replaced `1.1102230246251565e-16` by zero. They would be. I suppose `1.1102230246251565e-16` isn't different enough from zero to avoid the problem.

Comment: @user2640045 I just tried the case of setting `vectorB` as a multiple of `vectorA` and - interestingly - it sometimes produces `nan`, sometimes `0` and sometimes it fails and produces a small angle of magnitude `1e-8` ... any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just tried the case of setting vectorB as a multiple of vectorA and - interestingly - it sometimes produces nan, sometimes 0 and sometimes it fails and produces a small angle of magnitude 1e-8 ... any ideas why?

Yea and I think that's what your question boils down to. Here is the formula from [the berkeley paper due to Kahan](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Triangle.pdf) that you've been using.
[image: angle formula] Assuming that `a≥b`, `a≥c` (only then is the formula valid) and `b+c≈a`.
If we ignore `mu` for a second and look at everything else under the square root it must all be positive since `a` is the longest side. And `mu` is `c-(a-b)` which is `0 ± a small error`. If that error is zero you get zero which is btw. the correct result. If the error is negative the square root gives you nan and if the error is positive you get a small angle.

Notice that the same argument works when `b+c-a` is non zero but smaller than the error.

Comment: @wikikikitiki Isn't it odd that we talked about exactly this just yesterday?

Comment: Mmh, in this case, what would be the preferred approach to avoid `nan`? Two strategies that come to mind are: (1) clip `mu` at 0, or (2) set it to `0`  if it is `eps` close to it. However, I have no good motivation for either, other that they feel natural.

Comment: How about you check if the strong triangle inequality is fulfilled. And if it's not i.e. a≈b+c you return 0 if vec_a and vec_b point in the same direction on pi or 180° if they point in opposite directions. You can figure out if they point in the same direction with the dot product. If it's positive they point in the same direction if it's negative it's opposite directions.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger Btw. you could also check if the vectors are linearly independent (that's equivalent). Maybe it would feel more justified to say: my vectors are linearly dependent they must form an angle of 0 or pi/180°. Edit: But thinking about it. The former is probably better because you know your formula works if a,b,c fulfilled the strong triangle inequality. Since the paper says that and you don't have to worry about numerics then :).